# Calculation of sample size

Tags: sample-size

I'm doing a comparative study between two warming devices for patients undergoing renal transplant surgery.. patients are divided into two groups and are warmed by the device of that particular group.. the core temperature of the patients are measured at half an hour.. the difference in mean temperature which is clinically significant is taken as 0.3*C.. Now I should know the minimum number of subjects to be recruited in each group to start my study

Comment: Can you explain your question properly?

Comment: Too little information. You'd also need to specify: 1) the designated type I error rate, it's usually the threshold of p-value below which we'd reject the null hypothesis, 2) the power, and 3) the standard deviation of your temperature measurement, and if it's the same across the two groups.